# ejecucion de python en sublime text3, no muestra resultados en consola inferior

Tags: python, consola, sublimetext3

buenas tarde,mi problema es algo que no he conseguido en google, tengo sublime text 3 con python 2.7x y al ejecutar cualquier programa sublime text no me muestra los pasos del programa, solo muestra que finalizo, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: podrías poner tu el código que estás utilizando. Lo más probable es que no estés utilizando print en los resultados que quieres mostrar en consola. Sublime no es una consola de python, así que debes pedirle explicitamente que imprima los resultados deseados.

Comment: kronos, ¿a que te refieres con que no muestra los pasos del programa? ¿en tu código imprimes en consola cada vez que se ejecuta cierta accion? Debo pedirte que porfavor puedas [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código que estas usando y clarificar un poco mas tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien, yo tenia el mismo problema que Kronos, ejecutaba y lo único que aparecía era "finalizado", busque en todas las opciones del programa y en Tools o herramientas está la opción build with o (CTRL + SHIFT + B) elegí la opción python y lo solucione. Espero que les sirva mi dato ;)

Comment: También tenía el mismo problemas que Kronos y lo resolví con la sugerencia de Lucía.Bel 16, a la cual agradezco el aporte porque ya andaba algo desanimado, ya que apenas comienzo en el mundo de la programación.

Answer (score 0):

En resumen dos diferencias:

el <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd> : es para `REPL` esto se arregla como mencionan en otros post ingresando a preferencias y editando el *Key Bindings*.

el <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> :es para el build, esto se arregla poniendo : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shit</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> y haciendo lo que mencionan arriba :)